# Simple program results in "Stack Smashing"

Tags: c

I am trying to concatenate two strings and then make a system call in a UNIX environmental. The program does what I want but terminates with the error `*** stack smashing detected ***`

Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    //Check if there is an arg otehr than file name
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        int i;
        //argv[0] is prog name start at 1.
        for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
        {

            char st1[] = "wc -l ";
            strcat(st1, argv[i]);
            printf("%s",system(st1));
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nExiting. No input files given.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sounds naughty... the issue is obvious.  you're smashing the stack!

Comment: This problem is one that a book should have been able to answer. Our time is better used on people who have read their book, completed the exercises successfully and are still having problems. Which book are you reading?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, 50 shades of...

Comment: @modifiablevalue I'm not reading a book. I'm just writing programs as they come to me when I have a new idea and learning via the web. I don't see how this is not a relevant question to stackoverflow. If you think its a waste of time then don't answer it or flag it.

Comment: @Nick If you need to ask stackoverflow what's wrong with this code then your current method of learning clearly isn't working. How can you be sure that your C programs will continue to work well into the future, on systems unimaginably different to those existing today? The problem with undefined behaviour is that it might appear to work as intended until an otherwise meaningless update to compiler or system. I suggest K&R's "The C Programming Language, Second Edition".

Comment: @modifiablelvalue That doesn't make any sense. Stack is a Q&A site and if you read the faq of the website you would see it clearly states that the purpose of SO is for "**a specific programming problem**" which is what I had until hmjd answered my question. My style of learning is my own and works great. I suggest you read the faq before taking a self righteous stance and telling people that their question is a "waste of time" which btw is also very rude.

Comment: If you could verify your facts correctly, then you might be as aware of your confusion as I am. If you had continued to read for another fifteen seconds, you would have noticed it suggesting that you "Please look around to see if your question has been asked before". I suggest carefully reading [this faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Asking people to find and duplicate answers to your questions, because you won't read a book, is self-righteous. You spent all of that time asking questions and reading answers, so why not read a book written by the professor godfathers of C?

Comment: This has obviously gotten off topic. Stack smashing is a common and broad error. If you can find an exact of my question then flag it as a duplicate that why such things exist. The fact of the matter is that my question was on topic and could be of use to another person while your comment was backhanded and unhelpful. So don't patronize me with, again, your self righteous attitude. Stackoverflow is much better than any book I've read or will read because it answer my exact question whether I ask it or not. If you don't enjoy helping people go else where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str1` is not large enough to contain the resulting string as it only has enough elements to contain `wc -l \0` (it is a `char[7]` array). The call to `strcat()` writes beyond the bounds of the array, overwriting memory it should not.

Dynamically allocate enough space, calculated based on the length of the incoming argument to ensure enough memory is available:

```
char* s = malloc(7 + strlen(argv[i])); /* 7 is 6 for "wc -l " and null term. */
if (s)
{
    sprintf(s, "wc -l %s", argv[i]);

    free(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char st1[] = "wc -l ";
strcat(st1, argv[i]);
```

`st1` will be allocated on the stack, just large enough for the string constant used to initialise it. You then append another string, potentially (almost certainly) corrupting the stack.